# Linux syscall for cloning files

Tags: linux-kernel, clone, system-calls

I remember that years ago I read about how there was a new syscall in Linux for instantaneous copying of files (cloning) but now I cannot find it. Does it really exist?

The closest thing I found was:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html

Comment: `sendfile(2)` is probably the closest one to what you describe. Unless you are referring to the new (yet to be merged) [`readfile`](https://lwn.net/Articles/825324/), but that doesn't really have much to do with your description.

Comment: Oh both syscalls are also of interest to me. Thanks!

Comment: Some non-Linux Unix OS have `clonefileat`. Linux does have an ioctl to perform a CoW clone on filesystems that support it: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlonerange.2.html

Comment: Are you thinking of LVM snapshot?  That instantly (almost) creates two copies of a whole filesystem

Comment: I believe the `ioctl` syscall is what I was looking for.

Comment: When is sendfile() better than copy_file_range() or visa versa? Re https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081715/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-copy-many-files-programmatically